# gnuplot, ubuntu 12.10, kile, texlive2012

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, gnuplot, kile

How can I download and install gnuplot for ubuntu 12.10?  I can't find it on the software center or in repositories.  Maybe I am not calling it right.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a LaTeX question to me.

Comment: @TimHoffmann I guess I am blind.  It was there thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. When I type "gnuplot" in the software center search, it's the first hit.

Anyway, you may try from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```

If this does't work either, you probably have some issues with the configuration of the package repository. That's rather a Linux/Ubuntu question than TeX related.